# Android file manager that preserves nanoseconds

Tags: android, file-management

I'm looking for an Android file manager that preserves modification nanoseconds when moving/copying. This is honestly a very basic requirement, that all the file managers I've tried so far appears to lack.

Only this one is a must. The other requirements that are highly desirable are:

- Tabs.
- Bookmarks.
- List view shows timestamps.
- For a particular entry, show owner, permissions, timestamps.

Comment: The ext4 file system of Android (I assume you are using a relatively new version like >2.3) supports time stamps with nanoseconds. What makes you think your current file manager (which?) does not preserve nanoseconds?

Comment: @jmizv I tried a few, currently using *MiXplorer*. To see timestamps after copying a file, I use the `stat` command, in *Termux*. The modification second and nanosecond fields are both zeroed.